# Accepting a Dictionary as Command Line Argument

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

I have a code which receives a variable length Dictionary as input from another program. What my program needs to do is to accept and parse the values in the dictionary and declare them as global variable to be used in the program. How do I go about it? I am using Python3.

So, my program will be called from another program: like: myprogram.py Dict and Dict will contain multiple keys with each key having multiple values...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sys` and `json` module to archive this

```
import json, sys
data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
print (data)
```

And then

```
python3 test.py '{"foo": ["bar1", "bar2"]}'
```